# Microsoft Graph API - Option to access only specific events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I have an app that requires a user to provide access to their calendar to use a specific feature.
The permission I specifically ask for is -

`"calendars.readwrite"`

Some of the users have an issue with this and are requesting a solution so that my app can only access those specific events where the attendees are the employees of their company. Is there a permission level solution Microsoft provides for this?

Comment: If you want to restrict the calendar events/range then you can use calendarview, but it won't let you what you look for - such as granularity permission (say, calendars.readwrite) or inbuilt functionality doesn't exist at this point with Graph API. If you want Microsoft to implement that feature then consider filing a feature request/uservoice or upvote the [existing one](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict the calendar events/range then you can use calendarview, but it won't let you what you look for - such as granularity permission (say, calendars.readwrite) or inbuilt functionality doesn't exist at this point with Graph API. If you want Microsoft to implement that feature then consider filing a feature request/uservoice or upvote the [existing one](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/37796059-restrict-permissions-to-app-only-azure-ad-applicat).